# asp.net error : Column ambiguously define, when migrate to other server

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, ora-00918

I have ASP.Net application, It using mix .net framework, there are project with ,net framework 1, 2.0 and 3.5. buat they are in separated project / location. And its running well before.
I have a problem when I migrate my application from old development server to new one, FYI, my old server is windows server 2003 32 bit with oracle 10g, and my new server is windows server 2008 64bit with the same oracle version. 
I have set all configuration identically in both servers.  using same database schemas, and same application.
Overall, the application running well, but I was surprise when I found some error page while I running application in new server. error message is : ***ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined*** 
I don't know how the error happen, whereas in old server, no error at all with identically configuration.

any one have same problem ?
is it because 32bit & 64bit ?

I'll so thankful for your solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell why you are receiving this result.  You should adjust your database procedures so there is no ambiguity so you won't have to deal with this problem ever again.

Comment: but, why when I run it on my old server, there is no problem anymore ?